# Why do the short pulses in ultrawideband localization result in high accuracy?

Tags: propagation

I am currently reading about ultrawideband localization and came across the statement, that the short pulse duration that is used in UWB (for example ~2ns with 500MHz channel bandwidth) results in a high spatial resolution.

Quote:

> "The large absolute bandwidth,
> in US from 3.1 to 10.6 GHz [1] and in Europe from 6 to 8.5 GHz [2], corresponds to a very ﬁne time resolution in the order of hundreds of picoseconds which translates
> to spatial resolution in the order of centimeters. The very ﬁne time resolution allows a direct path to be easily dis-tinguished from the reﬂected paths" (From the paper ["Ultra-wideband Technology-based Ranging Platform with Real-time Signal Processing"](https://www.iis.fraunhofer.de/content/dam/iis/de/doc/lv/ok/paperuwb/Ultra-wideband_Technology-based_Ranging_Platform_with_Real-time_Signal_Processing.pdf))

Why is this the case?

What I can see is that the short pulse duration has benefits when it comes to multipath propagation. Since it is less likely that a direct and a reflected pulse overlap destructively or arrive at the same point (antenna) within <2ns of each other, so you can still differentiate them.

Why does the length of the pulse affect the ranging accuracy?

The short pulse travels from one antenna to another and will arrive after some time, depending on the distance.

If I make the pulse longer, the bandwidth gets smaller, and depending on the shape the leading edge would be flatter.

Can someone explain this and maybe point to a booksource or chapter where I can find further information about it or what to search for?

Comment: It is a general property that the shorter a pulse is the more precisely it can localize things in space/time. Without going into a lot of math, imagine that you're trying to feel how big something is with thick, padded gloves on. You will have a harder time then with thin surgical gloves on. It is the same idea here, using a larger thing for localization blurs out the precise location more than a small thing.

Comment: Also note that your quote does not claim higher accuracy (which depends on a lot of things), but more specifically resolution, that is the ability to resolve two reflections. It is saying that shorter pulses are less likely to overlap and thus are better at resolving. That doesn't necessarily mean higher accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

The authors of this paper are using a Time-of-Arrival (TOA) method to estimate distance. The accuracy of this method is directly proportional to how well you can resolve the instant of arrival of the signal pulse. This depends on the jitter and edge sharpness of the arriving signal, both of which improve with bandwidth.

Wikipedia has a nice article on [UWB ranging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UWB_ranging), in particular see the section titled "Ranging."